# How to access this string in function help please

Tags: android

Hello there is a problem what is wrong ? help me please

```
public class Function {
    public String name; // I want access this string in GetSessionName();
    public void SetSessionName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String GetSessionName(){  // error in this line always return null value
        return name;
    }
}

String value = new Function().GetSessionName(); // always return null value
```

I want access this string (name) in GetSessionName() Help me please

Comment: Where are you setting its value?

Comment: What is error? Please post logcat!

Comment: for store as session name like in PHP **SESSION['value']**

Comment: as you create new instance of `Function` class this must be null ( new Function().GetSessionName(); ) always, you need work with the object that you set this value to that, and if this value not changed and one value store in `name` you can make as `static`

Comment: SetSessionName(username); its done

Comment: shayan pourvatan please can you tell me example how to do that :P

Comment: it is getter setter method?

Comment: if one value is store change  `public String name;` to `static String name;` and if not you must post more code.

Comment: `public class Function {
 public String name;
 public void SetSessionName(String name){
  System.out.println("Assign Var "+name);
  this.name = name;
  System.out.println("Assign2 Var "+this.name);
 }
 public String GetSessionName(){
  String session = new Function().name;
  System.out.println("GEtName Var "+session); // always return null value
  return session;
 }`

Comment: Function getdb = new Function();   getdb.SetSessionName(username); // working perfect   Function getdb = new Function();   
  String session = getdb.name; // return null value

Comment: Thanks  shayan pourvatan its worked

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple logic error, check below in the code.
Long explanation:
Your value in your getter "name" refers to the local reference of name rather than the instance reference of name. To get the instance reference you have to use this.
In addition though, you should be setting your "name" property on init rather if you are going to chain new Function().GetSessionName();
or do lazy instantiation that checks real quick and then sets a default value.

```
public class Function {
public String name; // I want access this string in GetSessionName();
public void SetSessionName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
public String GetSessionName(){  // error in this line always return null value
    // return name; THIS LINE NEEDS TO BE CHANGED TO BELOW
    return this.name;
}
}

String value = new Function().GetSessionName(); // always return null value
```

Comment: same returning value null

Comment: Did you read the rest of the comment regarding setting an initial value either through lazy instantiation or with your initializer? Currently your value will be null since you haven't put anything in it.

Comment: Careful, static String name means something very different than public String name. Glad you got it working though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your local variable. You have declared it but you have never assigned a value. Here is a simple Java example which you can run, though I have not used chaining.

```
public class Function
{


        private String name; // I want access this string in GetSessionName();

        public void SetSessionName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String GetSessionName(){  

            return this.name;
        }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Function func = new Function();
        func.SetSessionName("A String"); // assign a value to your variable

        String value = func.GetSessionName(); //value will hold "A String"
    }

}
```